# if внути try except

Tags: python

У меня возникла проблема при написании бота ВК.

Из функции `tochats` подаётся в цикле запрос в функцию `write_chat` на отправку сообщения. Но, если вылезла капча, то весь процесс должен приостановиться (я это сделал с помощью `input()`).

Но, к сожалению, после того, как я введу текст в `input`, цикл не начнёт исполняться дальше, а просто прекратит свою работу.
Как сделать, чтобы цикл продолжал свою работу после того, как я сниму весь процесс с паузы?

Код:

```py
def write_chat(comu,text):
    for x in range(1):
        try:
            vk_session.method('messages.send',{'chat_id':comu,'message':text,'random_id':random.uniform(10300130, 20300130)})                            
        except Exception as e:
            if 'Captcha needed' in str(e):                    
                input(str(e)+' | Произошла ошибка. Возможно капча. Зайдите на аккаунт и сбросьте её для продолжения работы.\nДля продолжения работы введите любое сообщение и нажмите ENTER')
                vk_session.method('messages.send',{'chat_id':comu,'message':text,'random_id':random.uniform(10300130, 20300130)})                                    
                print(123)
            else:
                continue

def tochats(message,fromd):
    print('Запрос на рассылку по чатам сообщения '+message)
    response = vk_session.method('messages.getConversations',{'count':200})
    if response['count']:
        counts = 0
        fff = int(response['count'])*1.5
        write_msg(fromd,'Найдено '+str(response['count'])+' бесед. Рассылка займёт примерно '+str(fff)+' секунд')
        for x in range(int(response['count'])):
            print('tochats'+str(x))
            write_chat(x,message)
            counts = counts = 1
            time.sleep(1.5)                 
        time.sleep(3)
        return counts,int(response['count']) - counts

def tousers(message,fromd):
    print('Запрос на рассылку сообщений пользователям. Сообщение: '+message)
    response = vk_session.method('messages.searchConversations',{'count':200})   
    if response['count']:
        ptime = int(response['count'])*1.5
        write_msg(fromd,'Найдено '+str(response['count'])+' чатов. Отправка сообщений займёт ~'+str(ptime)+' секунд')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        count = 0
        for x in range(int(response['count'])):
            if response['items'][x]['peer']['id']:
                try:                    
                    write_msg(response['items'][x]['peer']['id'],message)
                    count = count + 1
                    time.sleep(3)
                except Exception:
                    continue                
        return count,int(response['count']) - count
```

Comment: Уважаемый автор, ссылки имеют свойство устаревать или просто становиться недоступными по каким-то причинам. Рекомендую Вам впредь вставлять в вопросы непосредственно код.

Comment: Что-то в коде, который вы привели, нет никаких `input` и конструкции try-except тоже.

Comment: Ошибся. Вот код - https://pastebin.com/pPEVeAgd

Comment: А вы уверены, что он должен продолжать, он не закончил рассылку, например или метод, ошибку которого вы ловили в try, не мог бросить второй раз исключение? Цикл корректно завершается?

Comment: Уверен. Он выдал ошибку на 19 иде. То есть потребовал капчу.
Когда вылезает такая ошибка с капчей, весь процесс по логике должен приостановиться из-за моего input, но после того, как я ввожу текст в этот инпут, скрипт выходит из цикла с рассылкой. Как сделать, чтобы он продолжил дальше выполнять рассылку?

Comment: Тогда так, были ли ваши `123` выведены на экран?

Comment: Они не были выведены. После input был просто выход из цикла, в котором была вызвана функция отправки сообщения

Comment: Это произошло, потому что вам опять метод выдал ошибку, Вам нужно либо ждать дольше, чтобы капча пропала, либо научиться как-то ее обходить/вводить.

Comment: Еще не совсем понятен смысл `for` внутри функции `write_chat`

Comment: try можно использовать только в цикле, вот я его и создал.

Comment: Как можно организовать паузу при ошибки? И продолжить выполнение потока после снятия паузы?

Comment: Нет, try можно использовать везде) можно с помощью `input()`, если вас устраивает вариант снятия ее руками

Comment: А как ждать, когда капча не будет требоваться, это вопрос уже к API, который Вы используете.